# C++ WinInet FtpPutFile() Returning Error Code 5 (Access Is Denied)

Tags: c++, ftp

I have a basic sample I'm trying that is meant to upload a text file to an FTP server. The FTP server resides locally on my Windows 10 machine. I'm running an IIS FTP Site. When I connect through an FTP client with the same information I provide my C++ program I am able to add test.txt to the FTP Site. No authentication issues, no file extension filtering issues, no connection/firewall issues.

When I run my C++ program the error code returned is 5 (Access Is Denied). I am sure there is something right in front of me I'm not seeing. The user being used to connect in the code is an administrator. I also changed it to my own user that installed IIS and created the FTP directory, but same problem. Here is my code:

main:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string PathBase = "E:/Test";
    const std::string FileName = "test.txt";
    file_upload(PathBase, FileName);
}
```

string_to_wstring:

```
std::wstring string_to_wstring(const std::string& text)
{
    return std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end());
}
```

file_upload:

```
BOOL file_upload(std::string FilePath, std::string FileName)
{
    std::wstring tmpBase = string_to_wstring(FilePath);
    std::wstring tmpName = L"/" + string_to_wstring(FileName);
        HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
        HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"192.168.65.1", 21, L"testuser", L"password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
        BOOL Transfer = FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, &tmpBase[0], &tmpName[0], 0x00000002, 0);
        if (!Transfer)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to upload" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Response Info: " << InternetGetLastResponseInfoW << std::endl;
        }

        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
Failed to upload
Error: 5
Response Info: 00007FFFC349CB60
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the FTP server logs for clues?

Comment: Nothing in the logs unfortunately. For good measure I shut down the FTP Service, moved out previous logs, started back up, re-ran the program. The log file re-generated but nothing was written to them.

Comment: I know next to nothing about windows, but I'm guessing there's probably a way to raise the log level of that FTP service.. Maybe try raising the log level to the max and see if a clue appears. Also, Windows has some central log facility; inspectable with "eventvwr", maybe check if a clue is in there.. sorry I can't help you more, Windows is really outside my area of expertise.

Comment: No problem I am not extremely familiar with IIS myself. I'll see if I can increase log verbosity to DEBUG or something assuming that exists. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end())` is not the correct way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. Non-ASCII characters will not be converted correctly. Use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent instead, or use the `A` version of the WinInet functions instead of the `W` version. Also, when `FtpPutFile()` fails, you are not calling `GetLastError()` soon enough, writing to `cout` first can wipe out the error code. And `InternetGetLastResponseInfoW` is a function but you are not calling it, and you can't call it unless `GetLastError()` reports `ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR`.

Comment: I have changed my functions to use the `A` version and the upload is now working. In the long-run I'll fix my conversion function and try to switch back to the `W` version. Thank you for your help! From what I understand I can't accept a comment as an answer so if this is better left an answer or whatever the proper etiquette is I'll do that. Thanks again.